# Making tab content scrollable

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-tabhost

I have a simple structure inside my layout, with a `RelativeLayout` for my header and right bellow that, I have a `TabHost` with 3 different tabs. I'm just asking about the content of my first tab here. Right after the tabs and their labels, there are two `LinearLayouts` followed by a `ListView` which gets populated via adapter.

Problem is, after those two `LinearLayouts`, there's very little space for the `ListView` to be seen, so I'd like to make this entire tab content scrollable.

I tried putting the complete layout surrounded by `ScrollView`, that didn't work. Then I tried putting the `ScrollView` around different tags, but no matter where I put it, I couldn't get the desired effect. Is there any other approach to this, cause `ScrollView` doesn't seem to be a solution right now.

Here's the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPlayerName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="#9 Zlatan Ibrahimovic"
            android:textColor="#FFF"/>

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/player_details_playerLogo"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvPlayerName"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabHost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/rlTop">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"></TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="1">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/playerInfoContainer"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:background="#EEE"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:weightSum="1">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvPlayerDetails"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                            android:padding="10dp"
                            android:text="Oyuncu Bilgisi"
                            android:textSize="16dp"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/playerInfoFirstRow"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/playerInfoContainer">

                        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                            android:id="@+id/team_details_teamLogo"
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/se"/>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="125dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvPlayerNationalTeam"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="left"
                                android:text="Isvec"
                                android:textSize="18dp"/>

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvNationalTeam"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="left"
                                android:text="Milli Takim"
                                android:textSize="10dp"/>
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvPlayerAge"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:text="35"
                                android:textSize="18dp"/>

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvAge"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:text="Yas"
                                android:textSize="10dp"/>
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="70dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvPlayerHeight"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:text="1.84 cm"
                                android:textSize="18dp"/>

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvHeight"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:text="Boy"
                                android:textSize="10dp"/>
                        </LinearLayout>


                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/playerInfoSecondRow"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/playerInfoFirstRow"
                        android:layout_marginTop="25dp">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="80dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvFoot"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:text="Sag"
                                android:textSize="18dp"/>

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvPreferredFoot"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:text="Tercih Ettigi Ayak"
                                android:textSize="10dp"/>
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="90dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvPlayerPosition"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:text="Hucum"
                                android:textSize="18dp"/>

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvPosition"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:text="Posizyon"
                                android:textSize="10dp"/>
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="70dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvPlayerWeight"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:text="81 kg"
                                android:textSize="18dp"/>

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvWeight"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:text="Kilo"
                                android:textSize="10dp"/>
                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/llRoles"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/playerInfoSecondRow"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:background="#EEE"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvPlayerTeams"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                            android:padding="10dp"
                            android:text="Oynadigi Takimlar"
                            android:textSize="16dp"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/llRolesLegend"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/llRoles">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvYear"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                            android:text="Yil"
                            android:textSize="14dp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvTeam"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                            android:text="Takim"
                            android:textSize="14dp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvContract"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="144dp"
                            android:text="Kontrat"
                            android:textSize="14dp"/>

                    </LinearLayout>


                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/lvPlayerRoles"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/llRolesLegend"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>-->


                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/llPlayerCareerStatisticsTotals"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:background="#EEE"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:weightSum="1">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvPlayerCareerStatisticsTotals"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                            android:padding="10dp"
                            android:text="Kariyer Istatistikleri"
                            android:textSize="16dp"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/llPlayerCareerStatisticsTotals"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvMatches"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout"
                            android:text="Mac"/>

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/ivGoals"
                            android:layout_width="25dp"
                            android:layout_height="25dp"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/playerInfoContainer"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvMatches"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/ivAssists"
                            android:layout_width="25dp"
                            android:layout_height="25dp"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/playerInfoContainer"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivGoals"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/ivYellowCards"
                            android:layout_width="25dp"
                            android:layout_height="25dp"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/playerInfoContainer"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivAssists"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/ivRedCards"
                            android:layout_width="25dp"
                            android:layout_height="25dp"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/playerInfoContainer"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivYellowCards"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvTotalMatches"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout"
                            android:text="458"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvTotalGoals"
                            android:layout_width="25dp"
                            android:layout_height="25dp"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/playerInfoContainer"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvMatches"
                            android:text="345"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvTotalAssists"
                            android:layout_width="25dp"
                            android:layout_height="25dp"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/playerInfoContainer"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivGoals"
                            android:text="112"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvTotalYellowCards"
                            android:layout_width="25dp"
                            android:layout_height="25dp"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/playerInfoContainer"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivAssists"
                            android:text="76"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvTotalRedCards"
                            android:layout_width="25dp"
                            android:layout_height="25dp"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/playerInfoContainer"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivYellowCards"
                            android:text="21"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/listViewPlayerSeasons"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"/>


                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                </RelativeLayout>

            </FrameLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why don't you post your xml layout file here?

Comment: I've added the layout